# FormWizard click Chrome's back button on done() step

Tags: python, django, formwizard

As in subject, i got problem when i click on Chrome's back button on final view (after last step), of form wizard, it redirects me to first step as expected, but it also shows validation error for this first-step form. Is this typical behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

`done()` page is rendered after validating all defined forms. So when you click back it takes you to the last form, but since the form data content is cleared, form wizard throws validation error for the first form.

You can see here how the storage is cleared:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py#L328

You need to remember - done view clears data and so you're suppose to use this view to save form data into db and redirect (to prevent reloading). You should NOT use it to render another page.

Comment: thats usefull knowledge, I used that redirect to other view in done().  but now when i click back, it redirects me to last step (where i got summary of all steps) containing all data, even if I do  self.storage.reset() in done() method, then if i click let's say "submit", it redirects me to first step with no data, and validation errors

Comment: @user2466146 Can you maybe provide the code on github or somewhere, so I can take a look?, seems like a weird behavior I have never came across..